# ServiceStack : Resolve Request DTO from an url

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there any way to harness or reuse the internal servicestack url route-to-service resolution to obtain the matching request DTO of that URL?

For example we have a service aggregating a list of URL strings that point to different SS services - all of which generate and return a PDF:

```
    public class PDFAggregationService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public BigAssPDFResponse Any(BigAssPDFRequest request)
    {
        var response = new BigAssPDFResponse();


        //does something to fetches list of pdf generating urls
        var pdfRoutes = [
               "https://server1/route1/param/2/thing/1",
               "https://server1/route1/param/3/thing/4",
               "https://server1/route2/param/1",
               "https://server1/route3/param/1"];




        var pdfBytes = new List<object>();
        pdfRoutes.ForEach(url=>
        {

            var requestDto = ???? ;  // how to resolve a DTO from a random URL? 

            var response = Gateway.Send<object>(requestDto);

            pdfBytes.Add(response);

        })


        // does something to aggregate all pdfs into one
        // pdfBytes.ForEach(...) 

        return response;


    }
}
```

We want to avoid instantiating a JSONClient to just call the URLs, as all the called services are living inside the same AppHost as *PDFAggreationService*. (We'd also like to use a Gateway call so that we can leverage some complex logic that we have implemented in various request/response filters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a new `Metadata.CreateRequestFromUrl()` API that wraps the boilerplate that lets you do this in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/ec2db1b41558264a593255f190c8856538c123b6) (now [available from v5.0.3 on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget)) which you can use to do:

```
var requestDto = HostContext.Metadata.CreateRequestFromUrl(url);
var responseType = HostContext.Metadata.GetResponseTypeByRequest(requestDto.GetType());
var response = Gateway.Send(responseType, requestDto);
```

> Note your Request DTOs need to have the `IReturn<T>` marker interface to be able to use the Service Gateway.

This new API effectively wraps the boilerplate below to fetch the matching `RestPath` route definition which you can then populate with a `/path/info` and additional Dictionary of params that you can then send through the gateway, e.g:

```
var pathInfo = "/route1/param/1";
var queryParams = new Dictionary<string,string> { ... };

var route = RestHandler.FindMatchingRestPath("GET", pathInfo, out _);
var reqType = route.RequestType;
var requestDto = route.CreateRequest(pathInfo, queryParams, reqType.CreateInstance());

var resType = HostContext.Metadata.GetResponseTypeByRequest(route.RequestType);
var response = Gateway.Send(resType, requestDto);
```